# Laravel 5.2 and angularjs satellizer CORS

Tags: angularjs, cors, laravel-5, jwt, satellizer

I am building an api and I am having a lot of problems with the client side and the CORS.

The laravel app works correctly and I've used the **barryvdh/laravel-cors** to enable CORS in the server side. If I try the route with postman all works as expected and the app return the JWT. cors configuration:

```
return [
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
'hosts' => [],];
```

The problem starts when I want to login using angularjs and **satellizer** I am not able to receive the token due to the following CORS problem

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/authenticate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If I check the headers it looks like there is a problem with the server response:

[image: Server response headers]

I am using the laravel server to test it and grunt in the front-end.

I would like to ask if someone could help me here. I am stuck since the last week with this problem.

Comment: +1. OPTIONS call works - with headers, which are missing in response to the POST call. Have you found a solution already?

Answer (score 1):

I work also with Laravel 5.2 and have no problems with CORS after adding barryvdh/laravel-cors properly. Did you modified your routes.php file?

Route::group(['prefix' => '**api**', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function()
{Your API routes...}